# Warning on missing css rules?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, lint

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="this-rule-is-not-defined"></div>
```

I want to be notified about the non existing CSS rule `this-rule-is-not-defined`. Is there any setting for this in Visual Studio Code? Otherwise, which extension can do that?

Comment: look it - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/posts/6-awesome-css-extensions-for-vs-code

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thanks, `HTML CSS Support` provides a comand (CSS: Validate Attributes)! However, it has to betriggered manually. Any idea how to trigger that on save or automatically?